# Why is my image showing status 200 but not displaying image from s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, ejs

[This image shows that the image is uploaded, and fetched successfully but its nit displaying to the user, Can someone help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epCEl.png)

This is the code that Have written

```js
// Downloads from s3
function getFileStream(key) {
  const downloadParams = {
    Key: key,
    Bucket: 'icon-path-bucket',
  }

  return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream()
}

exports.getFileStream = getFileStream
```

and this is how I requested the image

```js
const { getFileStream } = require('./s3bucket')
app.get('/images/:key', (req, res) => {
  const key = req.params.key

  const readStream = getFileStream(key)

  readStream.pipe(res)
})
```

What can be done here?

Comment: if you navigate to the URL of those images in your browser, does the image display?

Comment: your code is working fine for me. please check the image again. you can also check the response in the browser network tab.

Answer (score 0):

seems your missing to [add the attachement](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.attachment)

the code with adding attachment would be

```js
        app.get("/images/:key", (req, res) => {
            const key = req.params.key

            const readStream = getFileStream(key) 

            res.attachment(key);
            readStream.pipe(res)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the contents of an album in the Amazon S3 bucket, the application's viewAlbum function takes an album name and creates the Amazon S3 key for that album. The function then calls the listObjects method of the AWS.S3 service object to obtain a list of all the objects (the photos) in the album.

The rest of the function takes the list of objects that are in the album and generates the HTML needed to display the photos on the webpage.

Related AWS doc: [Viewing Photos in an Amazon S3 Bucket from a Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html)